# Missing Property in Advanced Search

Tags: search, site-column

In my advanced search properties, I can't find my site column that I have crawled and mapped to a managed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up the list of managed properties requires more rights to the Search Service Application than most users have. So in order to avoid that problem MS has decided not to try to do that in the advanced search box web part.

Instead the list of properties are controlled by configuration of the web part.

On order for your managed property to show up you have to go to the advanced search page, put it into edit mode, select "Edit web part" on the "Advanced Search Box". Below the "Properties" header you then have the "Properties" property.

Click the elipsis (...) and copy the content of the textbox into a proper editor.
[image]

Add a `<PropertyDef Name="NameOfYourProperty" DataType="TypeOfYourProperty" DisplayName="a matching label"/>` for your managed property inside `<PropertyDefs>` and add a `<PropertyRef Name="NameOfYourProperty" />` inside each `<ResultType>` where you want it to show up.

Copy the xml back, OK, OK, Save, Test and Publish

Comment: I did do that <PropertyDef Name="ITCategory" DataType="text" DisplayName="IT Category" />
But it is still not showing up. The site has been incrementally crawled and fully crawled.

Comment: Did you also do the ResultType part? Crawling doesn't matter SharePoint isn't using that until you're doing the search.

Comment: <ResultType DisplayName="All Results" Name="default">
      <KeywordQuery/>
      <PropertyRef Name="Author" />
      <PropertyDef Name="ITCategory" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Description" />
      <PropertyRef Name="FileName" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Size" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Path" />
      <PropertyRef Name="Write" />
      <PropertyRef Name="CreatedBy" />
      <PropertyRef Name="ModifiedBy" />
    </ResultType>

Yep, I did. The custom site column works because I can search for it by doing the ITCategory:[desired query]

Comment: In the ResultType you have PropertyDef it should be PropertyRef

Comment: ....wow I feel dumb. How did I miss that? It's working now. Thank you.

Comment: Within the custom site column, is there way to make the choices I made populate into a dropdown menu for search.
http://i.imgur.com/Gq6rr.png

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.